# Custom library doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, robotframework

I am getting started with robot framework using python. I have following folder structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Tests have .robot files and Library has .py files.

This is what my robot file looks like

```
*** Settings ***
Library   /Library/CustomLib.py

*** Test Cases ***

Testing
    ${name}     generate random name    ${10}
    log to console ${name}
```

This is what my CustomLib.py file has:

```
import random
import string


__version__ = '1.0.0'

from robot.api.deco import keyword


class CustomLib:
  ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = __version__
  ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'

  @keyword('generate random name')
  def get_random_name(self, email_length):
      letters = string.ascii_lowercase[:12]
      return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(email_length))
```

At runtime it throws error that file doesn't exist and "No keyword with name 'Generate random name' found."

Though when I cmd+click on this keyword it takes me to the exact same method. I know it's some simple little thing but can't seem to figure out what.

Comment: While both Jiri's and Todor's answers should work, you could also pass `--pythonpath` argument to robot itself and give it a absolute path to the location where your LIBRARY is ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because of how you defined the path to the library during its import - you've prefixed it with `/`,  which means absolute path, e.g. "look for the directory Library from the root of the file system".

Just use a relative import, and you should be fine; if your tests are in the folder Tests, change the import to:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  ../Library/CustomLib.py
```

If they are in Tests/FunctionalityX/Another, then it would be like this, and so on:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  ../../../Library/CustomLib.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your library import path. If import the library this way you shouldnt have problems regardless of the directory where you are calling the robot cmd from.

```
Library    ${CURDIR}${/}..${/}Library${/}CustomLib.py
```

the CURDIR variable is

> An absolute path to the directory where the test data file is located.
> This variable is case-sensitive.

[Link](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#operating-system-variables)